# PayPal purchase goes to 2 different paypal accounts

Tags: php, jquery, paypal, simplecart

Here's the scenario:  I have a store that uses the jQuery simplecart (but not married to it). I have the physical goods of the store and ship them from my location. The single owner of the goods is somewhere else with a different PayPal account.  What I want to try to do is when a payment for goods come in, have the actual payment of the goods go to one account and the shipping costs go to my account.  Is this possible through a setup within PayPal or perhaps some type of PHP cart system or something else?

TIA!

Comment: Not likely ... user would have to approve 2 different payments to 2 different vendors. You would have to set up your own back end to do the transfers from your own account

Comment: You should overthink that useflow. If it's ungly and unintuitive people just won't use it and this sounds way too hacky. So even if it might be possible it's most probably not a good idea to tackle your issue this way.

Answer (score 1):

You have to come up with a script on your own (or hire someone) to fetch the transaction by id on Paypal under the first Paypal account and then recalculate how much is for shipping and how much is for sales.

Then you need to be aware that there will be fees when you transfer money to another account.

Finally you use their api to transfer money from first account to the second (thus paying commission fees to Paypal).

You can only have one Paypal account per person, so what you want is not possible without paying fees to Paypal (but perhaps, you could add a withdrawal to bank account).

Comment: I do have the PayPal set up as a business and it automatically puts in a flat fee for shipping to either domestic or international.  Was just wondering if there was a way to do it within the structure itself.  Thanks for the response...